# A simple way to check that $X:\Omega_1\times \Omega_2\rightarrow E$ is measurable?

Tags: probability-theory

I'm looking for a simple way to check that function is measurable, when the measurable space associated to its domain is defined as product space, for example $X:\Omega_1\times \Omega_2\rightarrow E$ is measurable, with $(\Omega_1\times \Omega_2,\mathcal{F}_1 \otimes \mathcal{F}_2)$ and $(E,\Sigma)$?

If $\Sigma$ is generated by a collection of sets $A$, then I would check if $X^{-1}(A) \in \mathcal{F}_1 \otimes \mathcal{F}_2$. However, I have no idea how $\mathcal{F}_1 \otimes \mathcal{F}_2$ will look like besides being able to write it as $\sigma(\{F_1\times F_2: F_i \in \mathcal{F}_i\})$...

Edit: [image]

Comment: The simplest ways depend on particular properties of the function in question ... what do you know about your function?

Comment: @GregMartin I'm looking at the definition of a progressively measurable stochastic process... The book states that any progressive process is adapted.  I was trying to understand how I would prove it.

Comment: Presumably you are referring to process defined on $\Omega\times[0,\infty)$. For progressively measurability regularity such as left-continuity and right limits (lcrl), right-continuity with left limits (rcll) or continuity a.s give you what you want. But in general, the problem depends on your process.

Comment: @OliverDiaz I've added the definition used in the book for a progressive process. The author then simply states that every progressive process is adapted...

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. Adaptability is simple. For any Borel set $f^{-1}(B)\cap(\Omega\times[0,t])\in\mathcal{F}_t\otimes\mathscr{B}([0,\infty)$ , where $\mathcal{F}_t\otimes\mathscr{B}([0,\infty)$ is the product $\sigma$-algebra. Then, as you know from elementary measure theory, if $V\subset (X\times Y,\mathscr{A}\otimes\mathscr{B})$ is in the  product $\sigma$-\algebra $\mathscr{A}\otimes\mathscr{B}$, then for any $(x,y)\in X\times Y$, the cross sections $V^y:=\{x\in X: (x,y)\in V\}$ and $V_x=\{y\in Y:(x,y)\in V\}$ are sets in $\mathscr{A}$ and $\mathscr{B}$ respectively.

Comment: @OliverDiaz many thanks... I was just thinking about that right now! ;)